# Apple External Accessory Protocol over iAP2 over Bluetooth low energe 4.0

Tags: bluetooth, analyzer, mfi

We are developing a product that communicate with iPhone use Apple External Accessory Protocol over iAP2 over Bluetooth low energe 4.0 but we find that we can not connect it through the BPA 100 bluetooth Analyzer wit ATS,so is the BPA 100 bluetooth a Analyzer support capture the Bluetooth low energe 4.0 datas? And this prodcut is it OK for MFi certification?

Comment: But Bluetooth LE is usually accessed through CoreBluetooth and requires no MFi?

Comment: 1) Regarding MFi certification, read documents provided by Apple at MFi Developer Portal.
2) @MihaylA.A is correct. BT-LE is usually accessed through CoreBluetooth, thus does not require MFi.

Answer (score 0):

1. MFi license is not required for the BLE connection. Apple providing the way you can create own BLE device and define properties with BLE Device Identifier. This is a very easy process to make a connection with the BLE Device. You can multiple articles on the internet. How to make a connection with BLE Device with the help of the Core Bluetooth framework.
2. Yes, We have to buy an MFi license. I want to develop own accessory, Which we can connect with iOS device thru cable or Bluetooth over IAP2 protocol. IAP2 Make connection with iOS then to Application and we can share maximum supported data over Bluetooth or cable connection. But BLE we can exchange maximum limit data. BLE connection consumes less data energy and exchange limit data compare to IPA2.